# How to reset autoincrement _key value in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to reset autoincrement `_key` value in arangodb. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a way to reset the auto increment in place. But how about:

- creating a new collection
- inserting all the data from the existing table , if any (without specifying the _key in the insert so the data gets a new _key).
- Deleting the old collection (after verifying the data was properly inserting in the new table).
- And finally, renaming the new table to the old table's name.